# How to serve simple static files along with html in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, static-files

I'm trying to send an HTML file with its CSS and JS files in NodeJS using `express.static()` but it doesn't work.

I've done the same thing as in some videos but I don't know where the problem is. And also when I open the `index.html` without the server, it display the styles.

This is my app.js(server):

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
});
```

HTML:

```
    <head>
        <link href="./public/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="./public/jQuery.js"></script>
        <script src="./public/main.js"></script>
    </head>
```

My public folder:

```
-node_modules
-public
    jQuery.js
    main.js
    styles.css
app.js
index.html
package.json
package-lock.json
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `app.use(express.static('public'));`, the string `'public'` refers to the **directory** where the module should search for static files, **not** the **URL path** which it should use for the search.

`src="/jQuery.js"` will map to the `public/jQuery.js` file.

To map URLs starting with `/public/` to the `public` directory, you need to specify that as the first argument to use:

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
```

And then `src="/public/jQuery.js"` will map to the `public/jQuery.js` file.